# How to inspect drive for zfs?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, zfs

I have a drive with ubuntu 16.04, then two drives as zfs, now I moved all the three drives to another computer, and can not see zfs pool residing in the two drives, sudo zpool list returns nothing, and I do some zpool imports, all complain about :

```
cannot import '/dev/disk/ata-ST340014AS_5MQ40HNH-part1': no such pool available
```

any idea how I can re-import the zfs pool? THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have tried to import a disk instead of the pool.

Try `zpool import` without arguments to list all found pools after a reboot (to rule out disk recognition errors when hotplugging disks). You should get a list of importable pools that can be imported by `zpool import <id>` or `zpool import <name>`.

If your export/shutdown on the old system was unclean, you might have to add `-f`, but try it without it first.